# Git not work on my Mac OS X 

Tags: macos, mac, git

I downloaded and install Git from http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/ .
After installing I can't use my Git installation.

```
thomas-macbook-:test zozo$ git init
-bash: git: command not found
```

What is wrong?

Comment: It compiles and installs flawlessly from source. Try that instead of this person's installer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add /usr/local/git/bin/ to your PATH, for example by adding to .profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: That syntax is not supported by all the shells that might use `.profile`. You should use `PATH=…; export PATH` if you want to put something like that in `.profile`. Or, feel free to stick something like that in `.bash_profile`/`.bash_login`. Note that *bash* will only use the first of `.bash_profile`/`.bash_login`/`.profile` that it finds and can read (so if the user has one of the other files, editing `.profile` will be ineffective (unless they ‘source’ .profile)).